# Facebook apk only returns basic_info when other permissions are set

Tags: android, facebook, session

I am trying to get the 'email' data from the Facebook apk, but have only succeeded in in getting the 'basic_info' back after setting any number of permissions. Here is my code:

```
private void update_buttons(){

  LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_facebook);

  authButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
                Session session = new Session.Builder(self).build();
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
                currentSession = session;
            }

            if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
                Log.i("LoginHome","Closing Session...");
                currentSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            }
            Log.i("LoginHome","Starting New Session...");
            OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) self);

            op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
            op.setCallback(null);

            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("basic_info");
            permissions.add("user_status");
            permissions.add("email");
            permissions.add("user_birthday");
            op.setPermissions(permissions);

            Session session = new Builder(ActivityLoginHome.this).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForRead(op);
      }
  });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                responseCode, intent);

    Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        Session session = new Session.Builder(self).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        currentSession = session;
    }

    if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                if(session != null){
                  Log.i("LoginHome","Session: " + session.toString());
                  Log.i("LoginHome","Session Closed: " + String.valueOf(session.isClosed()));
              }else{
                  Log.i("LoginHome","No Session");
              }
              if(state != null){
                  Log.i("LoginHome","State: " + state.toString());
              }else{
                  Log.i("LoginHome","No State");
              }
              if(exception != null){
                  Log.i("LoginHome","Exception: " + exception.getMessage());
              }else{
                  Log.i("LoginHome","No Exceptions");
              }

                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    Log.i("LoginHome","Session Opened...");

                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {

                                        Log.i("LoginHome","Returned Data...");
                                        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> map : user.asMap().entrySet()){
                                            Log.i("LoginHome","Key: " + map.getKey());
                                            Log.i("LoginHome"," Value: " + String.valueOf(map.getValue()));
                                        }
                                        get_server_id(user.getProperty("email").toString(), user.getId(), "Facebook");

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Has anybody else had this problem? Is there something I'm not setting correctly that makes the setPermissions call default to only the 'basic_info' value?

Comment: session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(op).setCallback(statusCallback));

Comment: Just tried your fix. Doesn't do anything different. When the session is printed in OnActivityResult I get this message: "Session: {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[basic_info, user_status, email, user_birthday]}, appId:*************}". I know that the permissions are there somewhere, but I am not getting anything besides the basic information from the GraphUser object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I figured this out after looking through the Facebook docs for the last day and a half. Hopefully this helps out somebody else as well. The code above works 100%, what wasn't working for me was the Facebook permissions that I needed to enable from the Facebook dashboard by taking my app out of sandbox mode. Just follow these steps if you are having the same problems with not being able to receive Facebook data.

**1) Go to the Facebook dashboard**

**2) Click on the Apps tab on the top and select your app**

**3) Click Status & Review on the left hand side of the screen**

**4) Click the button next to "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" to make the app live and turn off sandbox mode.**

You should be able to get the email data now from the Facebook api. The documentation for this apk is up there with the top worst written documentations I have ever seen. It's so simple. I feel like an idiot.